# Is it possible to strengthen this inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator from a normed space $X$ into a normed space $Y$.

Suppose that $T$ has the property that for a fixed $y\in Y$ and any $\alpha>1$, there exists an $x_{\alpha}\in X$ such that $$Tx_{\alpha}=y\ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ ||x_{\alpha}||<\alpha||y||$$. Is it possible to strengthen this inequality so that $\ \exists x\in X$ such that 
$$Tx=y\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ ||x||\le ||y||$$? I think it might be impossible but I cannot think of a counter example. Any proof or counter example would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $X$ is reflexive, you can strengthen the inequality (just pick a weakly convergent subsequence of $x_\alpha$ as $\alpha \searrow 1$).

In case $X$ is not reflexive, it might not be possible. By [James's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27s_theorem), there is a bounded linear functional $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{K}$ with norm $1$, such that
$$ |\varphi(x)| < \|x\|_X.$$
Now, pick $y = 1$ and you find no $x \in \varphi^{-1}(y)$ with $\|x\|_X \le |y| = |\varphi(x)|$.

To give an example, on $\ell^1$ you could consider
$$x \mapsto \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (1-1/n) \, x_n.$$